# How to set the selected property for Html ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here I have tried the followed code but I can't achieve it.
In the view page for dropdownlist SelectListItem ("objItem")  i can able to see the below mentioned properties and values but the list box is not selecting the "The Alchemist"

**ModelBindingControls.cshtml**

```
  <div>
   @{
       List<SelectListItem> objItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
       SelectListItem selectList = null;
       foreach(var item in Model.BookName){
           selectList = new SelectListItem();
           selectList.Text = item.Books;
           selectList.Value = item.Books;
           if(item.Books == Model.AwardedBook){
               selectList.Selected = true;   
           }
           objItem.Add(selectList);
       }
  }
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BookName, objItem,"Select Book", new { @id = "ddlBookName" })
</div>
```

The ObjItem values are

```
    [0] Index
    Selected =  true
    Text    =   "The Alchemist"
    Value   =   "The Alchemist"

    [1] Index
    Selected =  false
    Text    =   "The Davinci Code"  
    Value   =   "The Davinci Code"

    [2]Index
    Selected =  false
    Text    =   "The Harry Potter"  
    Value   =   "The Harry Potter"
```

**Model:**

```
public class AuthorDetailsModel
{
    public List<AllBookDetails> BookName { get; set; }
    public string AwardedBook { get; set; }
}

public class AllBookDetails
{
    public string Books { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ModelBindingControls()
{
    AuthorDetailsModel objModel = new AuthorDetailsModel();          
    objModel.AwardedBook = "The Alchemist";
    List<AllBookDetails> listBookObj = new List<AllBookDetails>();
    AllBookDetails objDetails = new AllBookDetails();
    objDetails.Books = "The Alchemist";
    listBookObj.Add(objDetails);
    objDetails = new AllBookDetails();
    objDetails.Books = "The Davinci Code";
    listBookObj.Add(objDetails);
    objDetails = new AllBookDetails();
    objDetails.Books = "The Harry Potter";
    listBookObj.Add(objDetails);
    objModel.BookName = listBookObj;
    return View(objModel);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of BookName i changed the property to Awarded book. Now it's working for me .

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BookName, objItem,"Select Book", new { @id = "ddlBookName" })
```

I changed to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AwardedBook , objItem,"Select Book", new { @id = "ddlBookName" })
```